# WAR deployed in local working but in remote not working

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I have a WAR (application developed in Java, struts, hibernate and Flex)to be deployed in Linux server with tomcat, in my local system it is working but in linux it is showing the main.html but not able to login

Comment: no clue on what is your dev system (i think it's Windows), no clue on which tomcat versions you run and no clue on what are the exceptions you get... Hard day for the answerers :-)

Comment: see/Post the logs for the application so someone can help

Comment: My system is windows and Tomcat version is 6, i m getting error #2032 Stream error.........in logs it is not showing any thng.

Answer (score 0):

I think, "2032 Stream error" is not actually a Tomcat error, but a Flex error (Action script?). So this may be related to Flex, which I don't use.

When I had a Google, a lot of the issues seemed to be related to SSL or security issues.

Sorry I can't be more help.